# Web Service WCF saída XML

Tags: asp.net, web-service, xml, wcf

Estou construindo um web service utilizando WCF. Criei o arquivo edmx, fiz a conexão com o banco onde estou informando as tabelas, views e procedures que estou querendo utilizar e meu arquivo .svc está assim:

```
' This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
Public Shared Sub InitializeService(ByVal config As DataServiceConfiguration)
    ' TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
    ' Examples:
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All)
    ' config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All)
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3
```

Quando rodo a aplicação aparece em xml as entidades que eu tenho.

```
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"          xml:base="http://localhost:25415/WcfBarramentoDS.svc/">
<workspace>
<atom:title>Default</atom:title>
<collection href="Produtos">
<atom:title>Produtos</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="Ocorrencias">
<atom:title>Ocorrencias</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="Colaboradores">
<atom:title>Colaboradores</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="Despesas">
<atom:title>Despesas</atom:title>
</collection>
</workspace>
</service>
```

Porém, ao escolher uma como por exemplo '.svc/Produtos' o meu retorno não é em XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="http://localhost:25415/Nome.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><id>http://localhost/Nome.svc/ProdutosTI</id><title type="text">Produtos</title><updated>2015-11-09T10:40:57Z</updated><link rel="self" title="ProdutosTI" href="ProdutosTI" /><entry><id>http://localhost/Nome.svc/Produtos(Codigo='01000123',Produto='nomedoproduto')</id><category term="Model.Produtos" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" title="Produtos" href="Produtos(Codigo='01000123',Produto='nomedoproduto')" /><title /><updated>2015-11-09T10:40:57Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Codigo>01000123</d:Codigo><d:Produto>NomedoProduto</d:Produto></m:properties></content></entry>
```

O que preciso mudar para obter a saída XML? 
E no caso só consigo retorno do que é tabela na minha entidade. Como faço para retornar em XML o resultado de uma view ou procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

O formato exibido no teu exemplo é 'ATOM' :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541106.aspx

Neste outro link tem tudo sobre odata, versão 2, 3 e 4
http://www.odata.org/documentation/

Luiz